# MYSQL: Perfect way to generate ID for 'comments' column

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, uuid

What would be the best option to generate a `comment_id` under `comments` table and a `notification_id` under `notification` table?
I know I can use `BIGINT`(auto incremented) for this purpose without worrying about consumption of ID's very soon. But would it be a good choice to use `UUID()`  (or using persistence specific library e.g `UUIDGenerator` in Hibernate) for generating ids for such requirements?
Other than the space allocation(large in UUID()), what are the cons of using `UUID()` as compared to `BIGINT/INT`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an interesting article with performance tests;
https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/12/19/store-uuid-optimized-way/

And based on performance, I choose, among other things, INT.